# Steeper p v curve in adiabatic process

Tags: thermodynamics, adiabatic

We know,in adiabatic process,the p v curve in indicator diagram is steeper than that of isothermal process.It indicates,in adiabatic process high change in pressure causes small change in volume compared to isothermal process,at the point of intersection of the two curves on indicator diagram.Apart from mathematics,how to understand this logically and intuitively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is relatively straightforward if you think if it not as changing pressure but changing the volume. In isothermic compression, heat is constantly transferred out of the system, keeping it cooler. Lower temperature means less frequent hits against the walls with less momentum, therefore it is easier to compress cooler gases than hotter ones. In adiabatic compression, the temperature rises during the process, thereby increasing the pressure more than by compression alone.